# retrieve all data from firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data structure:

```
{
 "Country" : {
    "USA" : {
       "Latitude" : 37.0902,
       "Longitude" : 95.7129
     },
     "Japan" : {
       "Latitude" : 36.2048,
       "Longitude" : 138.2529
     }
}
```

Hello. How do I retrieve the country key which is "USA" and "Japan" and also the Latitude and Longitude for both of them using just javascript. I would like to retrieve all as the number of country is increase. Thanks

Comment: Can you show desired output?

Comment: could console.log the country name and the coordinate

Comment: So you just want to log for example `USA` and `37.0902` `95.7129` etc?

Comment: yes. i want the log to appear like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `Object.keys()` and `forEach()` loop

```js
var obj = {
  "Country": {
    "USA": {
      "Latitude": 37.0902,
      "Longitude": 95.7129
    },
    "Japan": {
      "Latitude": 36.2048,
      "Longitude": 138.2529
    }
  }
}

Object.keys(obj.Country).forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  Object.keys(obj.Country[e]).forEach(function(a) {
    console.log(obj.Country[e][a]);
  });
});
```

You can also create string in each iteration of loop and `console.log()` that string. This way you can return `coutry` and `Latitude`, `Longitude` in one line.

```js
var obj = {
  "Country": {
    "USA": {
      "Latitude": 37.0902,
      "Longitude": 95.7129
    },
    "Japan": {
      "Latitude": 36.2048,
      "Longitude": 138.2529
    }
  }
}

Object.keys(obj.Country).forEach(function(e) {
  var str = e + ' ';
  Object.keys(obj.Country[e]).forEach(function(a) {
    str += obj.Country[e][a] + ' ';
  });
  console.log(str)
});
```

Comment: what if i want to retrieve the Latitude and Longitude separately? How to I do that?

Comment: i mean is that anyway to store latitude and longitude in separate string variable?

Comment: How to I retrieve latitude and longitude for the two countries where two different variable is used to store latitude and longitude. For example , var latitude = latitude of the country and var longitude = longitude of the country. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Maybe you should post that as new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// `inbound` is the JSON
var data = JSON.parse(inbound);
var usa = data.Country['USA'];
var usaLat = usa.Latitude;
// etc
```